# Problems dynamically allocating memory (in C)

Tags: c, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, function-definition

I am studying data structures. So I decided to implement a stack by myself using arrays. The problem is when the program tries to push an element when the stacks is full. My idea was to realloc() the existing pointer to the array, which I previously manually alocated memory with malloc() to increase the size of the stack by 1 then push the respective Item. After running the code on valgrind it shows me the error: "Invalid write of size4 ... 4 bytes before a block of size 16 alloc'd ".
Noting that I am a beginner so any help is appreciated.

```
typedef struct {
    int *v;    
    int cap;    
    int sz;
} stack;


stack* build(){
    stack *new = (stack*) malloc(sizeof(stack));
    new->v = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
    new->cap = 4;
    new->sz = 0;
    return new;
}

int is_empty(stack *s){
    return s->sz == 0;
}

int push( stack *s, int e )
{
    int success = 1;

    if (s->sz == s->cap){
        int*tmp =(int*)realloc(s->v,(s->cap+1)*sizeof( int));
        if (( success = tmp != NULL )){
            s->v = tmp;
            ++s->cap;
        }
    }

    if (success){
        s->v[s->sz++] = e;
    }

    return success;
}
int top(stack *s){
    return *(s->v);
}

int pop(stack *s){
    int value;

    if(is_empty(s))
        return -1;

    value = *(s->v);
    s->v--;
    s->sz--;
    return value;   
}

void destroy(stack *s){
    s->v -= s->sz + 1;
    free(s->v);
    free(s);
}

int match(char p1, char p2){
    if(p1 == '(')
        return (p1 - p2) == '(' - ')';
    else if(p1 == '[')
        return (p1 - p2) == '[' - ']';
    else
        return (p1 - p2) == '{' - '}';
}

int main(){
    int c;
    stack *s = build();
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){
        if(c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{')
             push(s, c);
        else if(c == ')' || c == ']' || c == '}'){
            if(!match(pop(s), c)){
                printf("no\n");
                destroy(s);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    puts((is_empty(s)) ? "yes" : "no");
    destroy(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your definition of `stack`?  (I assume it's a `struct` containing a pointer, capacity, and size.)

Comment: Your `realloc` call doesn't look right.  Look at the [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) for realloc.  You should be passing the original pointer to your originally-allocated memory block as the first parameter to the realloc function, not some calculation for some other memory address.

Comment: `s->v + 1 - s->sz` - are you sure about this `+1` here?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Include at the very least the definition of `struct stack`.

Comment: I already uptaded the code to show my stack structure, I will try to implement your suggestions give a second

Comment: My Idea with the calculations on realloc() was that the pointer which was poiting to last memory adress of the array, with the substraction and addition of 1 will point to the first memory block of the array. PS: I tried removing the calculations on my realloc(), including just the +1 and I still get an error

Comment: Why not just pass the address of the original array?

Comment: I passed the adress of the original array but  It stills doesnt work, I think its because its pointing to the last block of memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call of `realloc`

```
s->v = (int*) realloc(s->v + 1 - s->sz, sizeof(int) * (s->cap + 1));
```

is incorrect. The first argument of the function shall be the original pointer that points to the previously allocated memory or NULL.

Also this check within the function `push`

```
if(is_empty(s))
    *(s->v) = e;
```

is redundant.

The function can look the following way. Pay attention that the function should not issue any message. It is the caller of the function that will decide whether to output a message depending on whether a new item was added successfully or not.

```
int push( stack *s, int e )
{
    int success = 1;

    if ( s->sz == s->cap )
    {
        int *tmp = realloc( s->v, ( s->cap + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );

        if ( ( success = tmp != NULL ) )
        {
            s->v = tmp;
            ++s->cap;
        }
    }

    if ( success )
    {          
        s->v[s->sz++] = e;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Here is a demonstration program that shows the usage of the function `push`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int *v;
    int cap;
    int sz;
} stack; 

/* In case this is how I innitialize an array: */
stack *build() {
    stack *new = ( stack * )malloc( sizeof( stack ) );
    new->v = ( int * )malloc( sizeof( int ) * 4 );
    new->cap = 4;
    new->sz = 0;
    return new;
}

int push( stack *s, int e )
{
    int success = 1;

    if (s->sz == s->cap)
    {
        int *tmp = ( int * )realloc( s->v, ( s->cap + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );

        if (( success = tmp != NULL ))
        {
            s->v = tmp;
            ++s->cap;
        }
    }

    if (success)
    {
        s->v[s->sz++] = e;
    }

    return success;
}

int main( void )
{
    stack *s = build();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (!push( s, i ))
        {
            puts( "Error: not enough memory." );
        }
    }

    for (int i = s->sz; i != 0; )
    {
        printf( "%d ", s->v[--i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Of course you will need to write yourself a function that will free all the allocated memory.

Pay attention to that it is better to define the stack as a singly-linked list.

Comment: Thank you! With the implemations you gave me valgrind doesn´t show that error. That was really helpful. But I still get an error, which I had before I just thought It was from the reallloc(). Now when I try to free() the s->v it gives me the error: free(): invalid pointer. I will ink my full code, so I can show everything that I did. The problem that I am trying to solve is: they give a string and we check if the parentheses are well formatted(every open parenthese has a closing one), the input was {[a]b(c)}()[], output: "no"(should be yes). If you could help I will be really thankful!

Comment: Noting that I am novice in stockoverflow, so if theres anything I can do help you tell me! I really appreciated your effort to help me :)

Comment: @stfp04 I showed you how the function can be defined and provided a demonstration program that shows that the function works correctly. If you have some other problems then you should close the question selecting the best answer and ask a new question with your new problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the advice and help anyway! I will close the question and ask a new one, but anyway thank you for the help